# How to suppress switch warnings in esp-idf and cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, esp32, esp-idf

I have a project that was originally written for Particle devices, and we are moving away from their devices to ESP32. I have been working to port the code for one of our devices to esp-idf, and now receive a ton of warnings related to switch statements not having a default in them, and thus cannot compile. For some reason, whatever compiler Particle devices use doesn't care about this issue. While I could certainly go through and correct the code, this is not the time or place to do so and I need to suppress these warnings. Eventually we will correct in the original code and push to this fork.

```
../main/Services/ConfigurationParser.cpp:295:16: error: enumeration value 'psAmbientTemperature' not handled in switch [-Werror=switch]
```

I do not understand this platform or compiler well enough to know how I can suppress these until a later time, and have been unable to find information elsewhere. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ESP IDF build system enables the GCC option `-Werror` by default. This causes GCC to treat all warnings as errors. You need to tell CMake to reverse that, which requires adding a [command line option to GCC](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/build-system.html#controlling-component-compilation).

Assuming your code with warnings is entirely contained in component named "main" (which is the default) just edit the file `main/CMakeLists.txt` and add the line below to the bottom of the file to suppress only your specific warning:

```
target_compile_options(${COMPONENT_LIB} PRIVATE -Wno-error=switch)
```

Or this to stop all warnings from being treated as errors:

```
target_compile_options(${COMPONENT_LIB} PRIVATE -Wno-error)
```

Comment: I get a CMake error when using either of those in the main/CMakeLists.txt file: target_compile_options command is not scriptable

Comment: The error, "target_compile_options command is not scriptable", was because that line needs to go below the idf_component_register entry. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Good to hear, happy hacking!

Comment: this also works with `... PRIVATE -Wno-unused-local-typedefs ...` when compilation complains about `locally defined but not used [-Werror=unused-local-typedefs]` (e.g. when including `ets_sys.h`)